# how access any function from module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, restify

I create a server using **restify** framework in nodejs, but when i want to **respond()** funtion from **Function.js** it prints output **'hello undefined'** actully **expected output is 'hello world'**, i think **another function from Function.js is affecting** ... tell me how we access particular function from module?

**server.js**

```
var restify=require('restify')
var respond=require("./src/Components/FunctionalComponents/Function")
var server=restify.createServer() //server created


server.get('/hellopj',respond);

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("server started...")
})
```

**Function.js**

```
module.exports =function respond(req,res,next){
        res.send('hello world ')
}

module.exports =function insertFun(req,res,next){
    res.send('hello '+req.params.name)
}
```

Comment: Try, `respond.respond` in `server.get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to export module in Nodejs.

- Default Export *(Once without any key)*
- Named Export. *(Once with key)*

Right now, you are using default export which is being replaced by the last `insertFun` export as each file can have only one default export.

For Named Export, Just give each export a key and import with that key and you are good to go.

**Functions.js:**

```
module.exports ={
   respond: function respond(req,res,next){
       res.send('hello world ');
   },
   insertFun: function insertFun(req,res,next){
       res.send('hello '+req.params.name)
   }
};
```

**Server.js:**

```
const { respond } = require("./src/Components/FunctionalComponents/Function");

//......

server.get('/hellopj', respond);

//.....
```

Comment: if i want to insert data in table using this insertFun() what should i write there in Function.js ?

Comment: Just export insertFun from similar to response .const { respond, insertFun } = require("./src/Components/FunctionalComponents/Function");